# get checkbox state in in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

how can i get the checkbox state of my checkboxes inside a gridview?
i have programmatically added them like so,

```
  foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
  {
     tbCell = new TableCell();
     cbGV = new CheckBox();
     tbCell.Controls.Add(cbGV);
     gvr.Cells.Add(tbCell);
  {
```

Normally i would get the state of the checkboxes like so(below) when they are inside an itemtemplate, but this is not working, so any ideas guys ??

```
  foreach (GridViewRow getRowItems in GridView1.Rows)
  {
      chkBox = (CheckBox)(getRowItems.Cells[0].FindControl("cbGV"));

      if(chkBox.Checked == false) 
      {
      chkBox.Checked = true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: on which event you are trying to get checkbox's value..

Comment: Why don't you add the checkbox in the template? you're mixing grid and table.

Comment: when i click this button, <asp:Button ID="SaveBtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="SaveBtn_Click"/>

Comment: Amiram Korach: maybe i will, but need to know if theres a workaround the way im doing it, if not or takes to loong to implement, then i just might go over to adding the checkboxes in itemtemplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add checkbox like this , i.e. as template column and than try to search this will also work rather than adding checkbox dynamically

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
<Columns> 
<asp:TemplateField> 
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbGV" runat="server" /> 
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

---

this is not working because you forgot to give id to element

```
cbGV = new CheckBox();
cbGV.ID="cbGV";
tbCell.Controls.Add(cbGV);
```

try to give id as above and than try to find checkbox in row

Comment: Pranay Rana: hey, thanks that did the trick, really been a frustrating problem since last friday.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
 tbCell = new TableCell();
 cbGV = new CheckBox();
 cdGV.id="cbGV";
 tbCell.Controls.Add(cbGV);
 gvr.Cells.Add(tbCell);
}


foreach (GridViewRow getRowItems in GridView1.Rows)
{
  chkBox = (CheckBox)(getRowItems.Cells[0].FindControl("cbGV"));

  if(chkBox.Checked == false) 
  {
  chkBox.Checked = true;
  }
```

}